# Static child rows (additional info) in DataTables in Twig-Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, datatables

I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine, Twig and DataTables. In a DataTable an overview of my entites are shown, with basic information. On click on a row I want to show additional information of the entity, as you can see [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

Here is the code (where applications is a Collection of my doctrine entities):

```
 <tbody>
                    {% for application in applications %}
                        <tr id="application-{{ application.id }}" data-child-information="{{ application | json_encode | raw }}">
                            <td>
                                {{ application.name }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ application.company.name | default("") }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ application.events.count }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ application.dateCreate | date('d.m.Y')  }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {% if application.dateSent %}
                                    {{ application.dateSent | date('d.m.Y')  }}
                                {% else %}
                                    {{ application.readableStatus(constant('APPLICATION_STATUS_OPEN', application)) }}
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
```

The documentation says an ajax call would be used for getting the data. But since I already have the information of my entity, I don't want to used AJAX but rather create the child rows from the beginning. What would be the best practise for this? As you can see I tried to savethe json encoded entity in the data-tag, so I can read it in the javascript function (see format function in DataTables documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to use the approach from the docs, it is just a suggestion.  You can simply inject the content of `data-child-information` into the details row :

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
       // This row is already open - close it
       row.child.hide();
       tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
       // Open this row
       row.child(tr.attr('data-child-information')).show();
       tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});
```

"work from home" demo ->  **http://jsfiddle.net/mgmL0f8c/**

Comment: Yeah, this is almost the same approach I wanted to use BUT I'm having troubles to pass my doctrine entity through data-child-information (see code in initial post). It's always "{}" in the html table.

Comment: Nevermind. I decided not to pass the whole entity but rather the html table through data-child-information.